# for all subcategories magento shows the description of their parent category

Tags: php, magento, view, magento-1.9, catalog

I have a problem in Magento of showing the subcategories description on the category listing page.

I have a number of categories with subcategories. PArent categories and each subcategory have their own title and description.

What exactly happens is that the title of the page in h1 tag and the description of subcategory pages are displayed from their parent category... The catalog/category/view.phtml file is just the standard file - not modified.

Could anyone please help to get the subcategories display their own descriptions instead of it's parent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

1. Login to admin panel.
2. Open catalog->category select subcategory from sidebar.
3. Now Click on **custom design** section.
4. And set **Use Parent Category Settings** to no.